# Filtered Stock on Hand list in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql

I have a POS sql database stock on hand table that I am struggling to work with.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
  ,[Style/Colour/Size ID]
  ,[Branch ID]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Start]
  ,[Quantity]
  ,[tc ho/bo delete flag]
FROM [Counter Intelligence Office].[dbo].[Stock On Hand]
```

From this table I am trying to gain a current stock on hand list (by [Style/Colour/Size ID]) per branch. Looks simple enough, but where I get stuck is the table stores historical on hand information right back to to the beginning of time for each item using the date field. So each [Branch ID] has multiple instances of [Quantity] for every [Style/Colour/Size ID] at different [Date].
What I need is a script to narrow the query down to only return the most recent [Date] instance of each [Style/Colour/Size ID] by [Branch ID]

Hope I have explained this well enough! Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Deon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
SELECT  
    SOH.[ID],
    SOH.[Style/Colour/Size ID],
    SOH.[Branch ID],
    SOH.[Date],
    SOH.[Start],
    SOH.[Quantity],
    SOH.[tc ho/bo delete flag]
FROM [Counter Intelligence Office].[dbo].[Stock On Hand] SOH
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       [Style/Colour/Size ID],
       [Branch ID],
       MAX([Date]) AS max_date 
    FROM [Counter Intelligence Office].[dbo].[Stock On Hand] 
    GROUP BY [Style/Colour/Size ID], [Branch ID]
) MAX_DATES 
     ON SOH.[Branch ID] = MAX_DATES.[Branch ID] 
    AND SOH.[Style/Colour/Size ID] = MAX_DATES.[Style/Colour/Size ID]
    AND SOH.[Date] = MAX_DATES.max_date
```

The subquery used in the inner join returns the most recent rows for each group of [Style/Colour/Size ID], [Branch ID].